# what's the meaning of "in the understanding of the times"

Tags: meaning

what's the meaning of "in the understanding of the times"

When a power center (state) seeks to grow, consolidate its authority, or modernize (**in the understanding of the times**), it is likely to harden its borders, centralize ...

Answer (score 1):

'Modernize' means different things to different people at different times.

At one time 'modernize' might have meant installing a bathroom in your house instead of throwing your waste into the street.

Now 'modernize' might mean improving your bathroom to have a bath, shower, bidet, jacuzzi, heating, expensive tiles etc

'In the understanding of the times' means whatever was thought to be modern at those particular times.